# Proper way to quote verses before a section

Tags: typography, epigraphs

I'm typesetting a book which — sometimes — has quoted verses in the beginning of sections. My first idea was to use something like `epigraph` to quote them, but then there's some very long quotes (up to 2 big paragraphs).

What would you recommend doing to get something quite homogenous between sections with only a single verse, and sections with 2 big paragraphs?

Edit:

I've found a solution that is not too ugly (but I'd like an honest opinion):

```
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \epigraphsize
  Élisabeth fut remplie d’Esprit Saint et s’écria d’une voix forte: Tu es bénie entre les femmes, et le fruit de ton sein est béni. Comment m’est  -il accordé que la mère de mon Seigneur vienne chez moi? Car voici: aussitôt que la voix de ta salutation a frappé mes oreilles, l’enfant a tre  ssailli d’allégresse dans mon sein. Heureuse celle qui a cru à l’accomplissement de ce qui lui a été dit de la part du Seigneur.

  Et Marie dit: Mon âme exalte le Seigneur et mon esprit a de l’allégresse en Dieu, mon Sauveur, parce qu’il a jeté les yeux sur la bassesse de s  a servante.
  Car voici: désormais toutes les générations me diront bienheureuse.
  Parce que le Tout-Puissant a fait pour moi de grandes choses. Son nom est saint, et sa miséricorde s’étend d’âge en âge sur ceux qui le craigne  nt Il a déployé la force de son bras; Il a dispersé ceux qui avaient dans le coeur des pensées orgueilleuses, Il a fait descendre les puissants   de leurs trônes, élevé les humbles, rassasié de biens les affamés, renvoyé à vide les riches. Il a secouru Israël, son serviteur, et s’est sou  venu de sa miséricorde, — comme il l’avait dit à nos pères —, envers Abraham et sa descendance pour toujours. 

  \rule[.5ex]{\epigraphwidth}{\epigraphrule}

  \raggedleft{\ibibleverse{Lc}(1:41-55)}
  \end{multicols}
```

It kind of emulates `epigraph` but it typesets the text on two columns on the whole width of the page:

[image: The current state of things]

In comparison, short quotes typeset with `epigraph` render like this:

[image: Simple epigraph]

Comment: Looks like a good idea to me. Could you perhaps show us how it handles single verse quotations? I am afraid you might run into some issues if you have a very short one/two-line quotation (in which case, perhaps you could just shift it over to the right column).

Comment: @ienissei: What I do is that I manually — for now — use either `epigraph` or this, when the quote is too long. Ideally, I'd write a command that would automatically switch between the two.

Comment: I added a simple `epigraph` example for comparison between the two.

Comment: Looks good to me, but there may be some issue with the vertical spacing. I don't know if you are using a glue or a fixed length, but there is a bit less vertical space in the epigraph (between the text, the line and the source). Depending on your layout, it may be relevant or not…

Comment: It might just be that I generated the second one later after having changed this setting actually :-)

Comment: You could also generally put chapter headings and epigraph on verso pages and start the text on the recto page as suggested in Section 6.5 on page 80 of the memoir documentation http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf Epigraphs are also handled with some detail in Chapter 13 of said document. Memoir uses `chapter` as the top-level sectioning command instead of `section` but so does the `book` document class which you probably should be using when typesetting a book.

Comment: Yes @Christian, I thought of opening sections left. It would look ok if all of my sections were 2 pages long, but some are 3 pages long, so I'd rather keep opening on the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My final implementation is very similar. It supports both 1- and 2-column environments with an option and has additional glues to fix vertical spacing:

```
\newcommand{\dvepigraphrefstyle}{\textsc}
\newcommand{\dvepigraph}[3][1]{%
\par\vspace{0pt plus -1fill}
\ifcase#1
% 0: do nothing
\or% 1: use epigraph
  \begin{savenotes}
  \epigraph{%
    \setlength{\parindent}{1em}
    #2
  }{\dvepigraphrefstyle{#3}}
  \end{savenotes}
\or% 2, use multicols
  \begin{multicols}{#1}
    \epigraphsize%
    #2

    \raggedleft{%
    \rule[.5ex]{0.95\epigraphwidth}{\epigraphrule}
    \dvepigraphrefstyle{#3}}
  \end{multicols}
\fi
\par\vspace{0pt plus 1fil}
}
```